# c# Pasar el reportsource de crystals reports desde otro form que no sea el que contiene el crviewer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Tengo una aplicación de windows forms, el cual tiene un Form1 que contiene el CrystalReportViewer. Lo que quiero hacer, desde otro form (Form2) llamar al Form1 que contiene el CRviewer y pasarle los datos, en el mismo Form1 me carga bien los datos de tal manera:

```
oCliente = ClaseClientes.SacarDatosTabla("Clientes", iIdCliente); // Saco los datos del cliente
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
string path = "../../crCliente.rpt"; // cargo el rpt
cryRpt.Load(path);
cryRpt.SetParameterValue("txtNombreCli", oCliente.sNombre);
cryRpt.SetParameterValue("txtNIFCli", oCliente.sNIF);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
```

Desde el otro Form2 creo que lo tengo todo, menos a la hora de acceder al CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource , si lo pongo tal que así:
`Form1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;` me dice "no es accesible debido a su nivel de protección".
¿Alguna idea?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasarle los datos en el `constructor` del form, algo como ser

```
public class Form1 : Form{

    privare readonly Cliente _datos;

    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(Cliente datos) : this() {
       _clientes = clientes
    }

     public void Form1_Load(...)
     {
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        string path = "../../crCliente.rpt"; 
        cryRpt.Load(path);
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("txtNombreCli", _datos.sNombre);
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("txtNIFCli", _datos.sNIF);

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
     }
}
```

Entonces en el otro form usas

```
public class Form2: Form{

  public void button1_Click(...){

     var oCliente = ClaseClientes.SacarDatosTabla("Clientes", iIdCliente); 

     Form1 frm = new Form1(oCliente);
     frm.Show();
  }
}
```

No se que tipo de dato devuelve `SacarDatosTabla()` por eso imagine seria una clase Cliente, pero esto debes adaptarlo

Comment: Gracias Leandro, pero no me funciona, aparte que en el form que contiene el crystalreportsview solo quiero mostrar la información, no quiero que tenga que cargar los datos, saludos.

Comment: podrias explicar mejor que seria por lo cual no funciona, es alg de la tecnica o es tas teniendo un error? los datos los obtienes en el form padre y se los pasas al form hijo (que contiene el control de crystal) solo para mostrarlos

Comment: Leandro, ya lo he conseguido, solo tenía que adaptar un poco más el código, gracias de nuevo.